# Lotus Notes API's (also used C++ Library) to obtain HTML Body format

Tags: c#, email, lotus-notes

Can you tell me, is there any way of extracting HTML body content (with inline image as an attachment) in lotus notes using Lotus Domino Objects(COM library in C#)

For eg : (i have tried the following code)

```
// p_objLotesNotesSession in this session i have got the database of one sample nsf that contains one mail with HTML Body and inline images. 

try           
{

obj_dxlExporter = p_objLotesNotesSession.CreateDXLExporter();

obj_dxlExporter.ConvertNotesbitmapsToGIF = true;

obj_dxlExporter.OutputDOCTYPE = false;


str_dxlContent = obj_dxlExporter.Export(docMailDoc);
```

When i get the content in str_dxlContent, it is in xml format 
but still in the body i won't get its proper formatting like font size, color etc.

I have also gone with C++ Libraries of Lotus notes still the API's won't give the formatting of HTML Body.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versionbs of Lotus Notes and Domino, there is a ConvertToMIME method in the NotesDocument class. Calling it with the code CONVERT_RT_TO_HTML (value = 2) should cause the Body field to be converted from rich text to a MIME part containing HTML.   See [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CONVERTTOMIME_METHOD_JAVA.html) for documentation.

What I can't tell you is whether that method is available via the COM classes. IBM does not necessarily expose all of their object methods through that particular interface. Also, the conversion is imperfect, so even if it is available through the the COM interface I can't be sure that it will meet your needs.